# scala try/catch not catching exception

Tags: scala, exception

I am fairly stumped by this. This should be simple and it is defying by expectations. I looked at similar SO threads, and they involved lazy execution or other issues that aren't relevant here.

FYI, this is with Scala 2.11.8. I'm calling into the Apache Kafka 0.10.1.1 library:

```
  def deleteTopic(zookeeperHostPort: String, topicName: String): Unit = {
    try {
      // the following log statement does execute. No surprise.
      logger.info("deleteTopic1")

      // If I uncomment the following simple `throw`, it is caught as expected.
      // throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("test")

      // The following TopicCommand.main throws an exception that isn't caught.
      TopicCommand.main(Array("--zookeeper", zookeeperHostPort, "--delete", "--topic", topicName))

      // the following log statement doesn't execute
      logger.info("deleteTopic2 (probably will not output)")
    } catch {
      case _: IllegalArgumentException => logger.info(s"Error deleting topic $topicName. It probably did not exist.")
      case e: Exception => logger.info(s"Error (${e.getClass.getName}) deleting topic $topicName. It probably did not exist.")
    }
    // the following log statement doesn't execute
    logger.info("deleteTopic3")
  }
```

generates an exception that isn't caught:

```
[ScalaTest-run-running-KafkaStreamSuite] ERROR kafka.admin.TopicCommand$  - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic testTopic does not exist on ZK path 192.168.50.20:2181
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.deleteTopic(TopicCommand.scala:166)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:68)
    at myapp.kafkautilities.AdminUtilities$.deleteTopic(AdminUtilities.scala:17)
    <snip>
```

Comment: The exception is probably being thrown from another thread.

Comment: Are you sure that that exception is not caught and the output you see is not some kind of logging that is going on inside of the Kafka library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka catches the exception, prints it and then does nasty thing - `System.exit`. See https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.1.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/TopicCommand.scala#L76:

```
  ...
67:  else if(opts.options.has(opts.deleteOpt))
68:    deleteTopic(zkUtils, opts)
69:} catch {
70:  case e: Throwable =>
71:    println("Error while executing topic command : " + e.getMessage)
72:    error(Utils.stackTrace(e))
73:    exitCode = 1
74:} finally {
75:  zkUtils.close()
76:  System.exit(exitCode)
77:}
```